# Searching for a way to access mobile highlights/quotes on desktop

Tags: android, reading

I am currently using ReadEra book reader on Android. I am searching for a way to access my quotes/highlights through a web application or a Windows application. I am okay with switching to a different application as long as it is not bloated with file editing features and can open .pdf and .epub files.
Any recommendations?